# Specifying a DirichletMultinomial in tensorflow probability

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow-probability

This is probably quite basic, but I can't figure it out -- I have a 100x5 matrix `y` that is generated from a Dirichlet-Multinomial and I want to infer the parameters gamma using tensorflow probability. Below is the model I implemented (for simplicity I'm assuming that gamma is the same for all 5 classes for now):

```
def dirichlet_multinomial_model(S, p, N, tau):
    gamma = ed.Gamma(2.0, 3.0, name='gamma')
    y = ed.DirichletMultinomial(500, tf.ones(5)*gamma, name='y')
    return y

log_joint = ed.make_log_joint_fn(dirichlet_multinomial_model)

def target_log_prob_fn(gamma):
  return log_joint(
     S=S, p=p, N=N, tau=tau,
     gamma=gamma,
     y=y)
```

When I try to sample from this using HMC, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Incompatible shape for initialization argument 'value'. Expected (5,), got (100, 5).

So specifying a length-5 vector of gammas seems to have resulted in the program expecting my data to be of shape 5x1. I cannot work out how to specify the model correctly -- any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try `sample_shape=(100)`?

Comment: Ah, that seems to work -- for some reason I thought I had to specify `(100,5)` as the shape of the samples. I do get a new error, but I think this may now be related to the type of the input data: `TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'x' has DataType int32 not in list of allowed values: bfloat16, float16, float32, float64`?

Comment: Solved that problem -- for some reason the `total_count` of 500 needs to be a float rather than an integer. Thanks for your help, if you post it as an answer I will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in my comment, the fix here is to use `sample_shape=[100,]` instead of `sample_shape=[100, 5]`. We have 3 notions of shape in the TF Distributions library (which Edward wraps): sample shape, batch shape, and event shape.

The event shape describes the shape of a single draw from the distribution. For example, a multivariate normal distribution in 5 dimensions has `event_shape=[5,]`

The batch shape describes independent, non-identically distributed draws; a "batch" of distributions. E.g., a `Normal(loc=[1., 2., 3], scale=1.)` has batch_shape 3 because of the 3 values passed to the `loc` parameter.

The sample shape describes IID draws from a *batch* of distributions. The resulting sampled `Tensor` has shape `S + B + E` where `S`, `B`, and `E` are the sample, batch, and event shapes, respectively.

In your example, the DirichletMultinomial has a concentration parameter with shape `[5,]`. This corresponds to the event shape of the distribution: every draw from this distribution will be a collection of 5 integers adding up to `total_count`. When you sample the distribution 100 times, you do indeed get a result with `shape=[100, 5]` but the 5 is implicit in the event shape of the distribution -- you're only drawing 100 samples, hence `sample_shape=[100,]`

Much of the above text is lifted from [this great notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks/Understanding_TensorFlow_Distributions_Shapes.ipynb), which has much more detail on TF Distribution shapes.

Hope this helps clarify things! Happy sampling! ^_^